# High-dimensional gradient between two points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, derivatives

Assume that I have two sets of parameters $x_1$ and $x_2$, and that $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Assume further that I have a function

$$f:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^M$$

so we also have $y_1=f(x_1)$ and $y_2=f(x_2)$, with $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^M$. My goal is to find the gradient of $y$ with respect to $x$:

$$ \nabla_xy =\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{d y_1}{d x_1} & \dots & \frac{d y_M}{d x_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{d y_1}{d x_N} & \dots & \frac{d y_M}{d x_N} \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

where $ \nabla_x=\left[\frac{d}{dx_1},\dots,\frac{d}{dx_N}\right]^T$ and $y=\left[y_1,\dots,y_M\right]$. Assume further that I don't have a closed form solution to the derivation of $f$. How do I approximate this gradient from the two points $x_1,x_2$ and $y_1,y_2$?

---

If you prefer to illustrate the process with an example, assume the following example with $N=3$ and $M=2$ (if you prefer any other example, feel free to propose one):

$$x_1 =\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
-2 \\
3 \\
\end{matrix}\right],
x_2 =\left[
\begin{matrix}
4 \\
-3 \\
-6 \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

$$y_1 = f(x_1)=\left[
\begin{matrix}
6 \\
1 \\
\end{matrix}\right],
y_2 = f(x_2)=\left[
\begin{matrix}
7 \\
-4 \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Seem unlikely to be possible. What you’re basically trying to do is guess a (hyper)plane by looking at only a single line near it.

Comment: Hm, you might have a point. In that case I believe I am looking for the hyperplane along which the single line is the steepest descent direction?